# Null pointer Exception for AnimationDrawable

Tags: android, animation

the main problem is that on small screen and small API device say 4" and api 8 code is working fine but for 7" tab and API 14 not working ,this my code for animationDrawble-

```
timerAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) timer_image.getBackground();
try {
        timerAnimation.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

i am getting null pointer exception at timerAnimation.start();

and my log for error is-

```
11-19 16:25:48.835: W/System.err(909): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-19 16:25:48.853: W/System.err(909):  at com.example.newpokergame.Play_Game1$1.onTick(Play_Game1.java:928)
11-19 16:25:48.863: W/System.err(909):  at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:124)
11-19 16:25:48.873: W/System.err(909):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-19 16:25:48.883: W/System.err(909):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-19 16:25:48.903: W/System.err(909):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
11-19 16:25:48.903: W/System.err(909):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-19 16:25:48.913: W/System.err(909):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-19 16:25:48.924: W/System.err(909):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-19 16:25:48.943: W/System.err(909):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-19 16:25:48.953: W/System.err(909):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is my file in `res/anim` folder in which i have different images-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/full_timer"
    android:duration="3000"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/timer01"
    android:duration="4000"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/timer02"
    android:duration="3000"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/timer03"
    android:duration="4000"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/timer04"
    android:duration="3000"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/timer05"
    android:duration="4000"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/timer06"
    android:duration="3000"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/timer07"
    android:duration="3000"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/timer08"
    android:duration="4000"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/full_timer_red"
    android:duration="3000"/>
```

and my xml file is resides in- `res/layout-sw600dp-land` and `res/layout-land` and `res/layout-xlarge-land`

Comment: What resource folder(s) does your drawable live in?

Comment: i have res/anim folder in which my different images live and my activity xml file resides in res/layout-sw600dp-land and res/layout-land